# Convert ISO8601 Datetime object(with T and Z) to a Datetime object having just T in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a requirement where i need to convert a IS08061 datetime object to a datetime object with just T.
For eaxample:
I started with a Datetime object from JSON equivalent to

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2023, 11, 15, 03, 30, 30, 444, DateTimeKind.Utc); //2023-11-15T03:30:30.444Z
```

I need to convert this to a Datettime object with a value of 2023-11-15T03:30:30.444. This needs to be a datetime type and not a string.

I am able to convert to string with T by doing -

```
string str = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But when i convert this back to datetime, I lose the "T".

```
DateTime val = Convert.ToDateTime(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //This returns 15/11/2023 03:30:30
```

I need the val to be 2023-11-15T03:30:30.444. Please suggest if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Repeat over and over again until it sinks in - `DateTime` objects *don't have a format*. They're simply a count of 100ns intervals since midnight on 01/01/0001. Anything you do with one that *involves* formatting necessarily means ending up with a string, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: _"I lose the "T""_ - you don't. String representation shown to you in debugger (or where do you check the `DateTime`) is not the actual stored date (which is not stored as string in memory). If you need to show it as string somewhere then you need to either provide format (if the display element supports it) or use `ToString` with appropriate format.

Comment: Don't get it. A DateTime has now T. If you want to see that when its a string then say so when converting it to s string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Damien and Guru. I learn't something new.
The DateTime type holds only the date and time along with certain properties. If you need to display the date and time in a specific format, we need to use ToString() method with format specifiers.
To fix my issue, I had to change the DateTimeKind to Unspecified from utc so that the ToString("o") method only prints T.